# Unable to load dynamic content using CURL and PHP

Tags: php, security, curl

Good day and salutation!
I am creating a simple web page to get a user and pass from a Form , and using CURL post these variables to another page to login, then show to result back ( I was gonna start from here then move on to accessing different pages). The problem is that some of the content of the site are loaded dynamically (Widgets). So when I get the result back the frame of the site loads up but the widgets are not rendering.
Error on loading the widgets from the second site :
**"ptBaseURI = String(location).match(//ps(c ... "**
Could this be a session problem ?
My php code:

```
$post_data['pwd']=$_REQUEST['password'];
foreach ($post_data as $key => $value){
$post_items[]=$key . '=' . $value;
}
$post_string = implode ('&',$post_items);
$tmp_file_name=tempnam("/tmp/","COOKIE");
$curl_handle=curl_init('www.targetsite.com/...');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$tmp_file_name);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$curl_handle=curl_init('www.targetsite.com/...');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$tmp_file_name);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$cArray = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
$newURL = $cArray[url];
echo str_replace('</head>','<base href="'.$newURL.'" /></head>',$result);
```

Comment: if those widgets are loaded/rendered/whatever via javascript, you will NOT be able to do anything with them in PHP, other than fetch the url they're loaded from. Curl is not a browser and only fetches/pushes things for you. it's up to YOU to interpreted the data that comes back, and that includes anything dynamic like JS.

Comment: True and thanks. But why do I get the baseURI error ? I believe these functions are there to insure security and if so , why not my user agent take care of that ?

Comment: sounds like a failing javascripts, as the javascripts often isn't use realative adresses, and there for the browser try to find it on your server where it dosnt exists

Answer (score 0):

on the result, you can use:
$result = str_replace('', '', $result);

then the broser should load the correct pages, but whitout the login cookie.

an other way is to set up a rewrite rule to fetch thos requst, and forward the requests
with curl to fetch the wanted page whit the login cookie.

Comment: Actually I do with : `$cArray = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
$newURL = $cArray[url];
echo str_replace('</head>','<base href="'.$newURL.'" /></head>',$result);
`